# CakePHP Form - generate new data using javascript before submitting form

Tags: javascript, forms, cakephp

Oke, I know I should be able to figure this out, but I am stuck. My experience is limited, especially with front end development (javascript).

I am developing an application in CakePHP and I want to do the following. The user enters data in a form; based on this data some other information is obtained from a third party API, using a javascript function; and then all this data is send to a CakePHP controller that stores the result in a database.

I got the difficult part working - obtaining the required data from the third party API. But I can't find how to add this information to $this -> request -> data before submitting the data. I know this should be easy, and the answer should be all over google, but I simply can't figure it out. My guess is the function looks something like the one below, but I am not coming further than that. I would like to stick to traditional forms, and learn about AJAX at a later stage.

Anyone a suggestion? Thank you!! :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function() {
  // ????????
  };
};​
</script>
```

Comment: `How to add this information to $this -> request -> data before submitting the data` The simplest way is by populating/appending hidden field(s) to the existing for with the relevant data. There's then no javascript in the form submission process, it's just a normal form.

Comment: ah yes thank you!! I tried that but it didn't work, but that was because the scripts were not being executed apparently. Now it works :)